# Does Chrome browser build verion 4.0.249.78 still support user script?

Tags: google-chrome, userscripts

I had a couple of user script that worked in version 3.5 by adding command line option --enable-user-script, after I upgraded to version 4.0, all those scripts stop working. Chrome browser is promoting its extension, some of user script can be replace by a chrome extension. Can anybody confirm if latest chrome browser stop supporting user script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Chrome builds allow you to install a user script as an extension with no modification.  Just open the .user.js in the browser.